# Rolling window count for a date interval in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization

I have a history of projects and their associated planned beginning and end times:

```
id   planned_start planned_end
1    2017-09-12    2017-09-13
2    2017-09-12    2017-09-14
3    2017-09-12    2017-09-13
4    2017-09-13    2017-09-13
5    2017-09-12    2017-09-12
6    2017-09-12    2017-09-20
7    2017-09-14    2017-09-15
8    2017-09-14    2017-09-20
```

I want to count the number of concurrent projects for each of the beginning dates for the projects above. Here's my logic for that:

```
for project_id in df['id']:
    start_date = df[df['id'] == project_id]['planned_start'].values[0]
    concurrent_projects = df[(df['planned_start'] <= start_date) & (df['planned_end'] >= start_date)]
    df.ix[df['id'] == project_id, 'concurrent_projects'] = concurrent_projects.shape[0]
```

Which produces this:

```
   id planned_start planned_end  concurrent_projects
0   1    2017-09-12  2017-09-13                  5.0
1   2    2017-09-12  2017-09-14                  5.0
2   3    2017-09-12  2017-09-13                  5.0
3   4    2017-09-13  2017-09-13                  5.0
4   5    2017-09-12  2017-09-12                  5.0
5   6    2017-09-12  2017-09-20                  5.0
6   7    2017-09-14  2017-09-15                  4.0
7   8    2017-09-14  2017-09-20                  4.0
```

However, I am aware how suboptimal, time-wise, the above `for` loop is. In reality, I have more than 500,000 projects for which I need to do this math. Can someone offer some advice on how to speed this up? I know there's got to be a pure-pandas or even numpy solution that would kill what I've got above.

Comment: Your current logic doesn't consider a project (`A`) concurrent with another one (`B`), if `A` starts after `B` but before `B` ends.  When you say "I want...concurrent projects for each of the beginning dates", do you mean you only want to know the count of projects that have already started and not completed yet at the point a new project begins?

Comment: Yes, only projects that, at the start of a given project *A*, have already started and may or may not have finished. Basically, I want to know how much is already on a project team's plate when they go to start a new project.

Comment: "already started and may or may not have finished": In order to be concurrent, why would you count a project that may have already finished?

Comment: If you only want projects that have already started, then do you want `df['planned_start'] < start_date` instead of `<=`?

Comment: It's been a long day... Yes, it should be "projects that started before and have not yet finished." And the `<=` filter is fine... I'd count projects starting at the same time as part of "the before."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vectorized way... but will blow up memory.  Still working on better vectorized way.  I have concept, just working on details while I pick up dinner.

```
s = df.planned_start.values
e = df.planned_end.values

s_ = s >= s[:, None]
e_ = s <= e[:, None]

df.assign(concurrent_projects=(e_ & s_).sum(0))

   id planned_start planned_end  concurrent_projects
0   1    2017-09-12  2017-09-13                    5
1   2    2017-09-12  2017-09-14                    5
2   3    2017-09-12  2017-09-13                    5
3   4    2017-09-13  2017-09-13                    5
4   5    2017-09-12  2017-09-12                    5
5   6    2017-09-12  2017-09-20                    5
6   7    2017-09-14  2017-09-15                    4
7   8    2017-09-14  2017-09-20                    4
```

---

My apologies, I don't have time to explain.  But I didn't want to leave you hanging

```
k = len(df)

d = np.column_stack([df.planned_start.values, df.planned_end.values + 1]).ravel()

i = np.tile([1, -1], k)
a = d.argsort()

f = np.arange(k).repeat(2)
r = np.zeros(k, int)
z = np.zeros(k, int)
m = np.zeros(k, int)

cumsum = 0

for j in range(f.size):
    x = f[a[j]]
    y = i[a[j]]
    r[x] = cumsum
    z[x] = (y + 1) // 2
    r += y * z
    m = np.column_stack([m, r]).max(1)
    cumsum += y

m

array([5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4])
```

Comment: I was hoping you might find this question :) ... and, yes, that definitely killed my memory. In reality I've got more than 500,000 projects. Cheers.

Comment: Good solution ~ !

Comment: I'm going to sit here for awhile and try to parse all of that, but thank you, sincerely, for following up.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution, by using `crosstab`, basically is using the `martix` of evens to do the calculation (Input `Dataframe` `df2`):

```
df=pd.crosstab(df2.planned_end,df2.planned_start,margins=True)
df=pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(columns=list(set(df.index)- set(df.columns)))]).fillna(0)
df2['concurrent_projects']=df2.planned_start.map(df.loc['All',:].cumsum()-df.All.cumsum().shift().fillna(0))



df2
Out[112]: 
   id planned_start planned_end  concurrent_projects
0   1    2017-09-12  2017-09-13                  5.0
1   2    2017-09-12  2017-09-14                  5.0
2   3    2017-09-12  2017-09-13                  5.0
3   4    2017-09-13  2017-09-13                  5.0
4   5    2017-09-12  2017-09-12                  5.0
5   6    2017-09-12  2017-09-20                  5.0
6   7    2017-09-14  2017-09-15                  4.0
7   8    2017-09-14  2017-09-20                  4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `apply` gives a roughly 3x speedup.

Current approach:

```
%%timeit
def concurrent_count_using_loop():
    for project_id in df['id']:
        start_date = df[df['id'] == project_id]['planned_start'].values[0]
        concurrent_projects = df[(df['planned_start'] <= start_date) & (df['planned_end'] >= start_date)]
        df.ix[df['id'] == project_id, 'concurrent_projects'] = concurrent_projects.shape[0]

concurrent_count_using_loop()

# 10 loops, best of 3: 21.4 ms per loop
```

With `apply()`:

```
%%timeit
def concurrent_count(project):
    valid_start = df.planned_start <= project["planned_start"]
    valid_end = df.planned_end >= project["planned_start"]
    return (valid_start & valid_end).sum()

df["concurrent_projects"] = df.apply(concurrent_count, axis=1)

# 100 loops, best of 3: 6.94 ms per loop
```